# UnboundLocalError, - reference before assignment

Tags: python, bisection

I have seen the solutions to similar errors like this one, but I still can't understand the error I'm having. This is the code:

```
current_savings = 0
total_cost = 1000000
r = 0.04
semmi_annual_raise_rate = 0.07
portion_down_payment = 0.25
monthly_salary = 10000


def Saving_Rate(portion_saved):
    for i in range(1,37):
        current_savings = current_savings * (1+(r/12)) + monthly_salary * portion_saved
        if i % 6 == 0:
            monthly_salary = monthly_salary * (1+semi_annual_raise_rate)
            month_savings = monthly_salary * portion_saved
    return(current_savings)

portion_saved = 0.2
Saving_Rate(portion_saved)
```

The error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'current_savings' referenced before assignment
```

The error seems to happen when I call the function `Saving_Rate()` and when I call the variable `current_savings` inside the function it doesn't call it from the global environment. Why?. If I already assigned it a value equal to 0 before calling the function.

Comment: You don't need `current_savings` or most other variables to be global variables. Just move them inside the `Saving_Rate` function

Comment: You can tell python explicitly that `current_savings` and `monthly_salary` are global variables by adding `global current_savings,monthly_salary` line just before `while` loop. Also `semi_annual_raise_rate` is supposed to be `semmi_annual_raise_rate` inside `while` loop.

Comment: @sshashank124 I need them to be global variables as I will use them also outside from the function environment. The function is just to do more readable/efficient the code, but I need those variables to be global.

Comment: @AjayDabas so you are saying when I define a variable in the global environment, I'm not defining it as a global variable?

Comment: You are already returning `current_savings` from the function. Why not use that value instead of trying to use global variables only? Using global variables (when you should clearly be using functions with arguments and return values) is **not** good design. Please try to fix your code accordingly